# Upload file into google drive using php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

If any function available to upload file onto google drive without using any oauth function (that is automatic upload)

Some google credential set (like refresh token) when uploading..

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  You will need to show us what you have tried yes you can send a refresh token to the PHP client library No you cant upload to Google drive without some form of authentication Service account or Oauth2(Refreshtoken)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Turn on the Drive API

Use this wizard to create or select a project in the Google Developers Console and automatically turn on the API. Click Continue, then Go to credentials.
At the top of the page, select the OAuth consent screen tab. Select an Email address, enter a Product name if not already set, and click the Save button.
Select the Credentials tab, click the Create credentials button and select OAuth client ID.
Select the application type Other, enter the name "Drive API Quickstart", and click the Create button.
Click OK to dismiss the resulting dialog.
Click the file_download (Download JSON) button to the right of the client ID.
Move this file to your working directory and rename it client_secret.json.
Step 2: Install the Google Client Library

Run the following command to install the library using composer:

php composer.phar require google/apiclient:1.*
Download and extract this zip file and copy Drive.php to vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/, replacing the existing file.

See the library's installation page for the alternative installation options.

Step 3: Set up the sample

Create a file named quickstart.php in your working directory and copy in the following code: